# Classifying elementary fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, fermions, dirac-equation, majorana-fermions

Familiar elementary (non-composite) relativistic fermions are of the Dirac, Weyl, and Majorana kinds. Are there other kinds allowed in principle by relativistic quantum physics? If not, why not?

Are there any classification theorems for fermions?

Comment: Where do you see elementary Majorana or Weyl fermions? E.g. Wikipedia: *"With the exception of the neutrino, all of the Standard Model fermions are known to behave as Dirac fermions at low energy (after electroweak symmetry breaking), and none are Majorana fermions. The nature of the neutrinos is not settled—they may be either Dirac or Majorana fermions."*

Comment: @Norbert Schuch, I agree with the quotation from Wikipedia. I'm asking about theoretical possibilities for fermions in relativistic quantum physics, not just what is realized in the Standard Model.

Comment: Since all of them appear in effective theories, which are low-energy theories of relativistic theories, all of them are compatible with relativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch, right. The references I used introduce Dirac, Weyl, and Majorana fermions case by case and show they are compatible with relativistic quantum physics. This left me in wonder if there are other compatible kinds of fermions. Perhaps there is some theorem that tell us there isn't (or is), but I haven't found one.